# Basic SharePoint web part C#

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, web-parts

I've never done work in C# before (although quite a bit in PHP), but have been tasked to make a SharePoint webpart.  I need it to pull list data from SharePoint.  I really am clueless as to where I should begin, so I'm starting by making a 'check to see if list exists' function.  This just checks for the string 'listName' and prints 'this list exists' to the page.

Can anyone help me with my code and at least set me on the rigth track?  Thanks.

```
namespace SlideShowWebPart
  {
    public class SlideShowGuide : WebPart
      {
        protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter output)
          {
            using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb("http://www.school.edu"))
              {
                string listName = "List123ABC";
                var lists = web.Lists;
                foreach (SPList list in lists)
                  {
                    if (list.Title.Equals(listName))
                       output.Write("<b>This list exists</b>");
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Looks like you are heading in the right direction, is this code not working?

Comment: It gives me an error that it's causing a problem, and the page doesn't load.

Comment: You should be able to find the exact error by either digging through the SharePoint Logs or by modifying the web.config: http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2007/02/01/5935.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The following may not be accurate, as it can be difficult to identify the issue without seeing a stack trace.**

`SPSite.OpenWeb()` takes a relative URL.  Try removing the host name and including only the path.  (In your example, there is no path listed).  If you are trying to open the current web, then you should be fine calling the no-parameter overload.

[SPSite.OpenWeb() Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.openweb.aspx)

```
using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb())
{
    // Your Code Here
}
```

If you need to use the URL to access your site, you can pass an absolute url into the `SPSite` constructor.

[SPSite(string) Constructor Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd587107%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://www.school.edu"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        // Your Code Here
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can get a reference to the current web like this:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
```

Be careful not to dispose of objects that you obtain from SPContext.Current, as this will cause issues with SharePoint.

Comment: unfortunately stack overflow really shouldn't be a lesson 101 course but more of a direct q & a site, this just promotes laziness from people not wanting to take the time to read the plethora of information available.

Comment: @Brian, I agree SO shouldn't be a 101 course, but it seems like the OP has a legit question.

@Kyle, I think you're right. The error most likely is coming from the call to OpenWeb(). OP should put a try/catch around his code and use the Output object to write the stack trace.

Comment: I wound up using SPSite instead of SPWeb, it was a problem with the URL reference.  @Brian, I agree as well that SO shouldn't be a 101 course, but I tried to make this a focused question.  I try not to post basic and open-ended style questions, and will make more of an effort in the future not to do so.

Answer (score 0):

you can use web.lists["listName"]  to check for existence of a list. Once you have the list you can reference the items via the same concept.

```
SPList list = web.lists["listName"];
list.items["ColumnName"]; // returns the value as a string representation
```

If you are looking to just get access to list data, grab yourself a copy of sharepoint designer, navigate over to www.endusersharepoint.com and check out the article series on the data view web part.

Comment: I beg to differ, he asked about someone pointing him in the right direction of accessing list data. That's exactly what I did, his question changed after asking comments.

Comment: No, he asked if someone could help identify what in his code is causing the webpart to error.

Comment: However, given that, your answer does point out a way that the OP could optimize his code.